# Tag Library supports namespace: http://richfaces.org/rich, but no tag was defined for name: subTable

Tags: jsf, richfaces

With Jsf I'm trying to make a table that contains a subtable (like this example)

http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf?c=dataTable

This is my code

```
<rich:dataTable id="tableExample" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700" border="0" var="var" value="#{myBean.list}" headerClass="capcalera" styleClass="taula">

                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="${var.idSollicitud}" />

                </rich:column>
                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Codi OVT</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="${var.codeTest}" />
                </rich:column>


<rich:subTable
                        onRowMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='#F8F8F8'"
                        onRowMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#000000'"

                        var="expense" 

                        value="#{peticioService.list}">

                            <rich:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">HEADER SUBTABLE</f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="HELLO"/>
                            </rich:column>                  

                    </rich:subTable>


            </rich:dataTable>
```

But, then I get this error message:

```
Tag Library supports namespace: http://richfaces.org/rich, but no tag was defined for name: subTable
```

I've read that rich:subTable is available since richfaces 3.0.0, but in my maven configuration I have 4.0 version.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has been removed in RichFaces 4.0. The showcase link which you've there is for RichFaces 3.3.3.

Check the following documentation:

- [Overview of all available RichFaces 4.0 components](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/)
- [Live showcase of all available RichFaces 4.0 components](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/)
- [Migration guide from RichFaces 3.3.x to 4.0](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration)

The ["Iteration components"](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration-ComponentsMigration-RichIterationComponents) section of the migration guide tells the following:

```
----------------+---------------------------+------------------------------------
RichFaces 3.3.3 | RichFaces 4.x             | Changes
----------------+---------------------------+------------------------------------
subTable        | not implemented for Final | n/a. But that lightweight variant
                |                           | should be discussed and implemented
                |                           | in future.
```

The closest what you can get in RichFaces 4.x is the [`<rich:collapsibleSubTable>`](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=subTableToggleControl&skin=blueSky).